# Redis how to write binary data to dump file?

Tags: redis

I want to know REDIS how to write binary data. 
It open a file not in "b" mode.

```
fp = fopen(tmpfile,"w")
```

*Any help in this regard.*

Comment: what actually you want to achieve out of this?

Comment: I want to know why I open the dump file with "vim" , and get messy code. It's like a binary file , but not open with "wb" mode.

Comment: It _is_ a binary file. And it's not meant to be open in a text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In liunx, fopen has no b mode, see fopen man doc:

```
  r      Open text file for reading.  The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.

   r+     Open for reading and writing.  The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.

   w      Truncate file to zero length or create text file for writing.  The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.

   w+     Open for reading and writing.  The file is created if it does not exist, otherwise it is truncated.  The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.

   a      Open for appending (writing at end of file).  The file is created if it does not exist.  The stream is positioned at the end of the file.

   a+     Open  for reading and appending (writing at end of file).  The file is created if it does not exist.  The initial file position for reading is at the beginning of the file,
          but output is always appended to the end of the file.
```